# How to store a (download) file inside iPhone device?

Tags: iphone, path, download, device, dropbox

Currently i am working in simple Drop box application in iPhone, Using Dropbox_SDK to develop this app, i have to store a file inside drop box path folder and its works good, then i tried to retrieve (download) that file from dropbox and stored inside a iPhone device, but the device path, i didn't know that, how to set the device path? please help me

Thanks in Advance

I tried this for your reference:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *DropBoxpath = @"/Public/sam.txt";
    NSString *devicepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
    [[self restClient] loadFile:DropBoxpath destDir:devicepath];
}
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedFile:(NSString*)localPath
{
    NSLog(@"File loaded into path: %@", localPath);
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"There was an error loading the file - %@", error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
         NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/", [paths objectAtIndex:0]];   

    //    // Download and write to file
         NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"dropbox url.com"];
         NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

         [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to use NSFileManager and document directory for saving files. NSFieManager operation is needed for same. You can also use third party API for downloading

https://github.com/H2CO3/HCDownload/

Answer (score 0):

This is for downloading the file form dropbox:

```
 -(void) DBdownload:(id)sender
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents directory
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Example.txt"];
        NSError *error;

        [self.restClient loadFile:@"/example/Example.txt" intoPath:filePath];

        if (filePath) { // check if file exists - if so load it:
            NSString *tempTextOut = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                                 error:&error];
        }
    }
```